# How to make a specific letter of a word bold and underlined in ssrs?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I am trying to make the first letter of a word bold and underlined. But I am having a hard time doing it.

e.g.
**S**ample Result

Comment: Markup type HTML plus an expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set Markup Type to HTML (Placeholder Properties, General), then create an expression.

Example:

```
  ="<b><u>" & LEFT(Fields!Header.Value, 1) & "</u></b>" & MID(Fields!Header.Value, 2, LENGTH(Fields!Header.Value)-1)
```

Comment: Thanks. I actually managed to solve it myself but I will still try this. Thanks for taking time to help.

Comment: No problem. If you found a better solution, please share :)

Answer (score 1):

Highlight the text of the textbox. On the properties set the **MarkupType** to **HTML**

The expression on your textbox should look like the one below

```
="<b><u>" 
& Left(Parameters!ReportParameter1.Value,1) 
& "</u></b>" 
& Mid(Parameters!ReportParameter1.Value, 2, Iif(Parameters!ReportParameter1.Value Is Nothing,0,Len(Parameters!ReportParameter1.Value)))
```

The Iif in the above expression checks for null values can be replaced with the maximum field character value.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I actually managed to solve it myself but I will still try this. Thanks for taking time to help.